# Couldn't get the API error response in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm using an API for recovering password for the user. From the UI ,user can enter their email to recover password. If the relevant email is not in the db , I'm getting error message with 400 Bad request as user not found as follows.

```
{
    "message": "Email or password is incorrect"
}
```

I have tried to access the error message as error.message. But I'm not getting the error message to console.. I'm getting 'error isi.a.throw is not a function' to console.

```
  recoverlogin(form:FormGroup){
    let email = form.value.email;
    this.userEmail = email;

    this.apiService.get('Users/recoverLogin/'+ email, true).subscribe((data) => {
     this.error = "";
     this.router.navigate(['/recover-verification']);
    },(error)=>{
      console.log(error.message);
      return error;
    });
  }
```

My get method as follows

```
get(url: string, authorized: boolean = false ) : Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(apiUrl + url, { headers: this.getHeaders(authorized) }).pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
}
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve]; `isi.a.throw` is nowhere in the posted code.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your example. But I will say that if your back end is sending a message to the front, then the front will interpret it as just another message and won't error. This makes perfect sense because the front did not error, the back did.

Comment: @Keenan Diggs- Please check the updated question. Thaks.

Comment: @ jonrsharpe- Please check the updated question. Thanks.

Comment: you don't need `.pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));` since your `subscribe` is handling.

Comment: Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(error))` and see what is printed.

Comment: You should check the response in the network tab and check the response of the Network tab. In your get method you should also use .then and .catch

Comment: Hi. @manish  I removed .pipe from get method. After that I printed console.log(JSON.stringy(error) as Heretic Monkey mentioned. Now I can get the message value. I think it's not necessary to .pipe for all other http methods as well

Answer (score -3):

Subscribe dosent have Error, it only receive data.

```
this.apiService.get('Users/recoverLogin/'+ email, true).subscribe((data) => {
 this.error = "";
 this.router.navigate(['/recover-verification']);
  console.log(data.message);
});
```

you only have reslove\reject on promise.

not on Obeservable.

Comment: The second parameter of the `subscribe` function is for errors.

Comment: Subscribe has 3: onNext, onError, and onComplete  http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html.